# Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present java spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to uplaod image from file in jsp page to aws bucket

I use this code:

jsp file tag:

```
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="changePicture()">
```

controller:

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/saveContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public @ResponseBody ModelAndView saveContact(@ModelAttribute Contacting Contacting,ModelAndView modelndView,HttpServletRequest request ,
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
 if (!file.isEmpty()) {

         byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();}...(Is not all function)
```

pom.xml:

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.1</version>
     </dependency>
```

MvcConfigration.java:

```
           @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
                public StandardServletMultipartResolver resolver() {
                return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```

When i run it i got this error:

```
  Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present
```

What can i do what incorrect in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Example below is for XML config, but you can adapt.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <multipart-config>
            <location>/tmp</location>
            <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>
```